# NSDate time issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting an value of **2015-04-22 10:43:57** from server but getting problem when converting into `NSDate`. I'd like to convert the same into `NSDate` into same format given in `NSString`. Here is my code

```
// getting from server

NSString *dateString=@"2015-04-22 10:43:57"; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

If I will get dateString with timezone then will it be resolved.

Comment: What is the problem? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.
I imagine you are having a problem with timezones while formatting. You culd addnit to your NSDateFormatter to specify if input date is from an specific timeZone

```
// set date format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
NSString *dateString=@"2015-04-22 10:43:57";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
dateFormat.timeZone=localTimeZone;
NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

OutPut: **2015-04-22 10:43:57 +0000**

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You just try adding this line to your code.

```
//This will set time zone of your device.You can change systemTimeZone to localTimeZone based on your need.

[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```